# Ordenar estructuras en C empleando llamadas al sistema

Tags: c

Tengo ya mi código realizado. Se basa en ordenar unas estructuras de un archivo .bin por notamedia. Lo tengo estructurado de tal forma que tengo un main el cual se va a encargar de abrir el archivo, hacer las comprobaciones de que todo está en orden. Llamar a una funcion ordenanotas (la cual le pasaré el descriptor del archivo ya abierto) y ver cuánto tiempo tarda en realizar el ordenamiento así como el numero de intercambios hechos.

Por otra parte, tengo la llamada a ordenanotas, la cual se va a encargar de recibir el nombre del descriptor y retornar el numero de veces que ha hecho un cambio de ordenamiento de la estructura. Esta básicamente se encarga de comprobar que todo esté correcto, saber el tamaño que tiene una estructura y ejecutar el metodo de la burbuja para hacer el ordenamiento.

También, tengo un .h donde voy a tener la declaración de la estructura struct evaluacion y la declaración del prototipo de la funcion ordenanotas()

El problema es que al ejecutarlo, me sale que el tiempo de ejecución es negativo y el numero de intercambios diferente al que tenia que darme (me salen 60 y me tendrían que salir 13989. Imagino que el metodo de la burbuja tendré alguna cosa que no consigo ver el fallo. A ver si alguno puede ver el fallo

Muchas gracias

main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "practica2.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


int main()
{
    struct timeval tiempo_Inicial, tiempo_Final;

    int archivo_Datos, intercambios = 0;

    time_t tiempo_Total = 0;

    archivo_Datos = open ("datos.bin", O_RDWR);

    if(archivo_Datos == -1){
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("El archivo se puede abrir correctamente\n");    

        gettimeofday( &tiempo_Inicial, NULL);
        intercambios = ordenanotas(archivo_Datos);
        gettimeofday( &tiempo_Final, NULL);


        tiempo_Total = tiempo_Inicial.tv_sec - tiempo_Final.tv_sec;
        tiempo_Total = tiempo_Total * 10E6;

        tiempo_Total = tiempo_Total + (tiempo_Final.tv_usec - tiempo_Final.tv_usec);


        printf("Intercambios: %d\n", intercambios);
        printf("Tiempo empleado: %ld\n", tiempo_Total);

        close(archivo_Datos);       

        if(close(archivo_Datos)==-1){
            printf("Error, no se ha podido cerrar el archivo\n");
        }else{
            printf("Archivo cerrado correctamente\n");
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

ordenanotas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "practica2.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int ordenanotas(int ar_Datos)
{
    int j=0;
    int tam_Archivo;
    int tam_Struct;                             
    int intercambios = 0;
    struct evaluacion struct1, struct2; 
    struct stat tamanio_Struct;

    if(ar_Datos == -1){
        printf("\nError, el archivo no está abierto\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fstat(ar_Datos, &tamanio_Struct) != -1){
        tam_Archivo = tamanio_Struct.st_size;               // Tamaño total del descriptor
    }

    tam_Struct = sizeof(struct evaluacion);                 // Tamaño de una struct del descriptor

    printf("El tamaño del archivo es: %d\n", tam_Archivo);
    printf("El tamaño de una struct es: %d\n", tam_Struct);


   for(j=0; j<tam_Archivo; j++){
        lseek(ar_Datos, j*tam_Struct, SEEK_CUR);

        read(ar_Datos, &struct1, tam_Struct);
        read(ar_Datos, &struct2, tam_Struct);

        if(struct1.notamedia < struct2.notamedia){
            lseek(ar_Datos, -(2*tam_Struct), SEEK_CUR);
            write(ar_Datos, &struct2, tam_Struct);
            write(ar_Datos, &struct1, tam_Struct);
            intercambios +=1;
        }
    }
    return intercambios;
}
```

y el .h:

```
struct evaluacion
{
    char id[16];        /*DNI o similar*/
    char apellido1[32];
    char apellido2[32];
    char nombre[32];
    float nota1p;           /* Nota 1er parcial*/
    float nota2p;           /* Nota 2do parcial*/
    float notamedia;        /* Nota media*/
    char photofilename[20]; /* Nombre del JPEG*/
    char photosize;         /* Tamaño del JPEG*/
    char photodata[16000];  /* Datos del JPEG*/
};

int ordenanotas(int archivo);
```

Comment: Este código no es C#, debe ser C, o C++

Comment: Es C, @Phi disculpa

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que tiene quedar 13989 intercambios?

Comment: Solucionado el codigo